# onLoad function phonegap android

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

Which code I need to replace with `onload` function?

I create a phonegap project, when I run it on the browser it's work fine, the `onload` function work, but on my android device - nothing.

What is the cause of this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call function like this onLoad of page

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function(){ alert("hello") });
```

Dont forget to add cordova.js or phonegap.js to your html files

**Updated As per the comments**

help.js(another js file)

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', LoadPage);

function LoadPage()
{
  window.alert("loadPage");
}
```

Here is a [Simplest JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/m5q2ugh0/), just follow the structure of Html file and run without adding extra files.

All the best

Comment: can I set some function inside of the anonimuse function, like this: document.addEventListener('load', onLoad());

Comment: Yes, Sure. You can use this like `document.addEventListener('load', onLoad);`

Comment: I need to add this line to the <head>, like this: <head document.addEventListener('load', onLoad);>.......</head>? or to the body inside of "onLoad"?

Comment: you can add this in between <head><script> document.addEvent..... </script></head>

Comment: I add it in the head but nothing... what can I do?

Comment: what is in your onload function ?

Comment: In this function I create request to get the Data from DB and put this data on the views.

Comment: I change the script to your script that you write in your answer, but its still not working, the alert not shown.

Comment: Try this jsFiddle demo into your html file in application https://jsfiddle.net/kkp8ajct/1/

Comment: It's work, but I want to take out the onLoad function to another js file; can I do it?

Comment: yes, add another js after this script in your file and if this is right answer you can mark this as a right answer from the upper left right mark

Comment: yes I will mark it, but before the marking I want to understand it well, I have another js that my onLoad function wrote there but when I run the code and call to this function its not work... do you have any idea about it?

Comment: You have to add your another js just after the document.addEvent... script in your page and it will work please check this jsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/kkp8ajct/2/

Comment: sorry for anoying you.. but it still not working, I add the script with my js file after the document.addEvent... script but its not working.

Comment: Can you please add your file data into JsFiddle and share link here so i can check where the actual problem is

Comment: Create JSFiddle then i will check where the problem is :)

Comment: Just replace your EventListner with this `document.addEventListener("load", LoadPage);` and it will work fine

Comment: can you add a link with the change that working well? it still not working for me :(

Comment: You havent to do nothing just, remove this line and script from head and add it to your another js file on the beginning, am updating the answer

Comment: can you help me? please Im so desperate... where is your update?

Comment: Kirankumar- thank you for your patience. do you have any idea to solve my bad problem??

Comment: I am sorry mate but I will try finding your problem tomorrow.. for now have to go

Comment: Hi, do you have any idea??

Comment: sorry but your update not working for me :( I will mark your answer couse your patience... thank you a lot!!!!